# how to load data in flowlayout based on scrolling in C# (Issue: flowlayout freeze)

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to load large amount of plants data in a flow layout when i select the category of data,
If i select category with more than 12000 data then, it takes more time to 
load data into flowlayout, so i need to load data based on scrollling flowlayout.

---

```
protected void category_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button category = sender as Button;
        string s;
        s = " ID: ";
        s += category.Tag;
        s += "\n Name: ";
        s += category.Name.ToString();
        PlantList_with_images(category.Tag.ToString());
    }
```

Above code helps to generate all category as button, while i click on a category ,then data regarding that specific category should load into second flowlayout

```
 public void PlantList_with_images(string value)
    {
        flowLayoutPanelPlantList.Controls.Clear();
        try
        {
            string expression;
            string sql;
            expression= " select [id],[code],[name] from [plantdetails] where categoryname ='" + value + "'";
            Datatable dt = DataAccess.GetTable(sqlfetcher);
            int currentImage = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dataReader = dt.Rows[i];

                Button b = new Button();
                b.Tag = dataReader["name"].ToString();
                b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click_Plant);

                string details = dataReader["code"].ToString() +
                "\n Name: " + dataReader["name"].ToString();

                b.Name = details;

                ImageList il = new ImageList();
                il.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
                il.TransparentColor = Color.Transparent;
                il.ImageSize = new Size(58, 60);
                il.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(img_directory + dataReader["imagename"]));

                b.Image = il.Images[0];
                b.Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                b.Size = new Size(190, 83);
                //b.Text.PadRight(4);

                b.Text += dataReader["code"].ToString();
                b.Text += "\n" + dataReader["name"].ToString();

                b.Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
                b.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                b.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
                flowLayoutPanelPlantList.Controls.Add(b);
                currentImage++;

            }
        }
        catch //(Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

---

The above code helps to load data to flowlayout, the problem is if i click on category with more than 1000 or 2000 or more plant data, it freeze up and take more time to load data, sometimes shows not responding,
Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Populating your controls should be done in it's own thread as to not block up the GUI thread.  When you add your controls add them all at once and not one at a time because each add is a block(not responding) on the GUI thread. You will still get a not responding when the controls are added but it should be less of a wait.

```
        public void PlantList_with_images(string value)
        {
            flowLayoutPanelPlantList.Controls.Clear();

            //Create a task to gather your controls. 
            //Inside of a task the UI will still continue to respond when gathering your controls
            //Change it from add 1 control at a time to AddRange after you have gathered your controls
            flowLayoutPanelPlantList.Controls.AddRange(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                List<Button> controlList = new List<Button>();

                try
                {                    
                    string expression;
                    string sql;
                    expression = " select [id],[code],[name] from [plantdetails] where categoryname ='" + value + "'";
                    Datatable dt = DataAccess.GetTable(sqlfetcher);
                    int currentImage = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        DataRow dataReader = dt.Rows[i];

                        Button b = new Button();
                        b.Tag = dataReader["name"].ToString();
                        b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click_Plant);

                        string details = dataReader["code"].ToString() +
                        "\n Name: " + dataReader["name"].ToString();

                        b.Name = details;

                        ImageList il = new ImageList();
                        il.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
                        il.TransparentColor = Color.Transparent;
                        il.ImageSize = new Size(58, 60);
                        il.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(img_directory + dataReader["imagename"]));

                        b.Image = il.Images[0];
                        b.Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                        b.Size = new Size(190, 83);
                        //b.Text.PadRight(4);

                        b.Text += dataReader["code"].ToString();
                        b.Text += "\n" + dataReader["name"].ToString();

                        b.Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
                        b.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                        b.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
                        //flowLayoutPanelPlantList.Controls.Add(b);
                        controlList.Add(b);
                        currentImage++;

                    }
                }
                catch //(Exception)
                {
                }

                //Return the list of controls
                return controlList;
                //When you return the controls you will get a pause when adding all the controls to the flowcontainer it is unavoidable.
            }));
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind support, but its not working, it shows "cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.Button>>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]
" And im using this on .NET 4

Comment: "Task.Run" is not running on .NET Framework 4, so i used "Task.Factory.StartNew",  that time i got the above error